# Como preencher um DataGridView manualmente, depois de ter utilizado "ToList()" do link como DataSource?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

Eu estou preenchendo o DataSource do meu DataGridView assim:

```
var enderecos = from endereco in EnderecoBusiness.Enderecos
                                select new {
                                    Logradouro = endereco.Logradouro,
                                    Numero = endereco.Numero,
                                    Cidade = endereco.Cidade,
                                    Estado = endereco.Estado
                                };

dgvEndereco.DataSource = enderecos.ToList();
```

Onde `EnderecoBusiness.Enderecos` me retorna uma lista do tipo `Endereco` que contém os atributos preenchidos pelos dados do banco de dados.

Porém se o usuário cadastrar no banco de dados outro endereço eu preciso adicionar uma nova linha nesse DataGridView.

Tentei fazer algo como:

```
string[] novoEndereco = new string[4];

novoEndereco[0] = txtLogradouro.Text;
novoEndereco[1] = txtNumero.Text;
novoEndereco[2] = txtCidade.Text;
novoEndereco[3] = txtEstado.Text;

dgvEndereco.Rows.Add(novoEndereco);
```

Porém recebo o erro :

> Não é possível adicionar linhas programaticamente à coleção de linhas de DataGridView quando o controle é associado a dados

Qual a melhor maneira de prosseguir ?

OBS: Também preciso que essa nova linha seja adicionada com algum pequeno icone nessa primeira coluna que a imagem abaixo está indicando com a seta, só para que o usuário fique ciente de qual linha foi adicionada

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta você refazer o processo inicial, que ele ira atualizar as informações do `dgv`.

```
var enderecos = from endereco in EnderecoBusiness.Enderecos
                                select new {
                                    Logradouro = endereco.Logradouro,
                                    Numero = endereco.Numero,
                                    Cidade = endereco.Cidade,
                                    Estado = endereco.Estado
                                };

dgvEndereco.DataSource = enderecos.ToList();
```

Comment: Eu acabei criando um método que se executa isso toda vez que é adicionado um novo dado no banco, mas toda vez que chamo essa função e faz uma consulta no banco que retorna várias linhas. Eu não teria problemas de performance com isso ?

Comment: Bom você vai ter um custo de processamento refazer essa lista e depois passar ela para o dgvEndereco, mas acredito que é a melhor forma de se fazer... talvez apareca alguem com uma resposta melhor! A proposito não esqueca de dar um Up e marcar como resposta se te ajudou...